# How should this chase go?

Tags: medieval, fauna

In a fantasy (ie quasi-medieval) setting, a large group of riders is pursuing a smaller group of riders over an effectively endless plain with no place to hide. Initial contact is made from, say, two miles away. No other groups are involved. How does this chase unfold?

Do the pursuers gallop as fast as possible, or follow at their optimal pace (fast walking)? Equally, to the pursued aim to outrun or outdistance their pursuers?

Does it make sense for either group to split up, especially if some within the group are faster or slower than others? Can a few individuals staying behind to delay the pursuers hope to do any good, or can faster members of the pursuing group do anything to get ahead and slow down their prey?

How long is likely to go on for before the pursuers either catch up with or lose sight of (say 20 miles) their prey?

Comment: This is a physic/math question not worldbuilding. How fast does pursuers go? Depend if they want to be home for supper or do they have 20 years to spare?

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY, an infinite plain doesn't also imply infinite endurance of horse and rider. There are other factors in play.

Comment: @Separatrix It means we need to assume both have same/similar speed. Bigger group is faster as they can create bigger wake so horses are less exhausted. Also there is already a question about two groups on horses.

Comment: Split the large group into smaller pairs, have each pair takes turn to chase the target's while the rest should be maintaining a comfortable distance. Once a target is showing sign of slowing down catch up and torture make sure the other can hear their scream.

Comment: The chase will unfold exactly as the story requires it to unfold. Maybe there is a hidden gulley in the endless plain and the fugitives know about it and use it to escape. Maybe the pursuers know that the fugitives are ideologically opposed to scattering and pursue them to exhaustion. Maybe a storm comes out of the blue allowing the fugitives to escape. Maybe the fugitives apply the same strategy as the [Horatii](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horatii_and_Curiatii), and lure the pursuers into becoming staggered and separated, so that they can be defeated in detail. Only the author knows...

Comment: They chase them until food for the horses runs out. Then they decide to settle their differences with a battle of wits, at least one of the people involved is a Sicilian.

Comment: Historically, such a pursuit did happen during the mongolian invasion of the Khwarezm Empire in 1219. You can try researching Jebe 'the arrow', Conn Iggulden also has a series of historical books on Genghis Khan and his dynasty that portrays the event incredibly well

Answer (score 3):

If both groups are on equivalent mounts and equivalently equipped then what the pursuers should do is maintain visual contact. Trying to close the distance would tire their mounts faster than the pursued. Allowing the distance to grow too far risks losing contact. Horizon distance is 2.9 miles for an average person standing at sea level, maximum visual distance in air is around 12 miles before clarity is lost beyond practical use.

On the other hand the pursued are pretty much stuffed, there's no way out on an infinite plane so all they can do is run until the horses are exhausted, at which point they'll also be too tired to fight back.

Options:

1. Stand and fight now while they're still fresh and they have the distance and time between them and the pursuers to rest and be ready to fight, assuming they're not too badly outnumbered, or
2. Scatter to the four winds and hope some of them can get away. Splitting the group is also number dependent, if the pursuing group is 50% larger, and each rider goes their own separate way, 50% of the pursued now only have one person following them. This gives a decent chance to stop and fight then regroup with a colleague. It also gives the pursuers pause to work out their priorities of who to chase with how many people and allows them to get a little more space into the chase.

Sooner or later they must stand and fight, or surrender. The sooner they do it, the more control they have of the situation.

Comment: Horizon distance will be a little greater if you sit on the back of a mount (unless the mounts are short-legged lizards or some such).

Comment: @KlausÆ.Mogensen, since both pursuers and pursued are mounted it'll be somewhere between the two values, but still less than the 20miles mentioned in the question assuming Earth-sized world and no other special circumstances.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the small group has a chance to save everyone. Not all horses have the same endurance and can walk at the same speed for the same amount of time. If they just stay all together their weakest horse determines their speed whereas the attackers could separate and send a subgroup with stronger horses to catch up with them. Additionally you can go much faster if you 2 horses per rider than if you have just one as you can switch them out occasionally.

So the defenders should separate into a group that is essentially sacrificed and only hopes to delay the attackers a bit and a second group that gets all the horses and tries to outride the attackers until there are out of sight. The smaller the second group the better their chances. The attackers also separate and produce a subgroup just big enough to defeat the defenders but equipped with more and better horses. As they are more numerous they should still get all or almost all defenders unless they screw up or happen to have significantly worse horses.

Answer (score 2):

I think it slightly depends on the aim of the fleeing group. Are they a simply fleeing aggressors and hoping to save everyone or at least as many as possible, with no objective beyond that, or are they in possession of the plans to the death star (well okay not the death star but some other MacGuffin) and it only matters that one rider escapes, as long as that rider gets the MacGuffin away the rest of the group are expendable?

I think most of the other answers have focused on tactics to save as many as possible, so I'll look at the other situation where the fleeing group just want someone to escape with the MacGuffin.

Horses can't go as fast as you might think, at least not for long: [this article](http://www.luckypony.com/articles/horse_long_gallop.htm) suggests a full 30mph gallop can be sustained only for a few miles. The average all-day sustained pace maintained by Pony Express riders was about 10mph, achieved alternating between a trot and a canter, and they regularly changed their horses in order to sustain this all day without exhausting the steeds. Assuming a mount + rider height of around 3m, they need to get [7.7 miles (double the horizon distance given by the calculator to account for both riders being mounted)](http://www.ringbell.co.uk/info/hdist.htm) ahead of the pursuers to be out of sight.

In that case, their best bet is to give it to the best fighter (archer by preference), ensure they have the fastest horse (lightest and with best endurance, not necessarily best sprinter) and best weapon and send that rider on ahead as fast as possible together with the rider with the next fastest horse. The aim of the rest of the group will be to disguise as long as possible the fact that two riders have gone ahead and to delay the pursuers as long as possible, at least 30 minutes. If it's possible to time the departure of the two fastest riders to coincide with bad weather, then so much the better.

The rest of the group should therefore keep any heavy armour, or at least the best armour available to the group. If possible during this time the rest of the group should kick up as much dust as possible to try to obscure the departure of the MacGuffin duo. Once those two are on their way ahead, the rest of the fleeing group should drop their pace off, continuing to kick up dust and spreading out so that the dust cloud is larger and so it's harder for the pursuers to round them up quickly. When the pursuing group closes to arrow range the fleeing group could start to fire on them (if horse archery skills permit). Once chased down their primary aim will be to cripple(or kill) as many of the pursuers' horses as possible, with a secondary aim to put up resistance for as long as possible, at least 30 minutes ideally. If some of this group can actually turn back and make the pursuers chase them back the way they have come from it will further aid the escaping pair in getting far enough away to be out of sight.

The duo who have gone ahead initially need to get significantly beyond visual range and have to trust their colleagues to give them enough time, since they will definitely lose control of the MacGuffin if caught by the full pursuing group.

Once well out of sight they should separate, riding in more or less opposite directions at about relative 70 degrees to their previous courses, and sticking to hard rocky surfaces where possible in order to minimise tracking. Splitting up at this point further dilutes any pursuers who make it this far as they have to follow not one but two sets of tracks, either of which might have the MacGuffin. Once well and truly out of the area they can afford to slow down a little: they probably need to make a few more random course changes (still roughly away from the last known position of their pursuers) and then find somewhere to lie low. At that point the aim changes from initial escape to avoiding reacquisition: horses and riders will need food and water, but water holes may be monitored etc. The MacGuffin also needs to be got to wherever it's needed. We're well beyond the initial chase mechanics and into plot details now though.

Answer (score 1):

There are several factors at play. You suggest that there are slower and faster riders in both groups. This means that the slowest in the lead group will eventually be overtaken by the fastest in the pursuing group. Since there are more in the chase group, they can spare a few fast riders to deal with these and still have fast riders enough to continue the chase. They might even circle around the stragglers and leave them for their own slower riders to deal with.

Splitting up makes little sense, The chase group is larger and can hence have several riders pursue each rider that splits off from the front group. If the chase group is only little larger, ganging up may not be possible for all who split away - eventually it will be one on one; but the chase group can leave their strongest people for that (and, statistically, their strongest are likely to be stronger than the strongest in the smaller group).

What might help is to try to fool the pursuers into having slow horses following a fast rider, if it isn't obvious which ones are fastest. This may allow this rider to get a away. Or you could fool the pursuers to send fast riders after a slow rider that looks fast. This rider will be caught, but it will give the remaining fast riders in the front group a better chance to get away. Such tactics will only work if the chase group isn't much larger than the front group.

What will really decide the chase is water. Horses need to stop and water every so often. The front group will not dare be the first to stop at a watering hole, since the pursuers will quickly catch up. The pursuers, however, can let some horses drink at every watering hole and then ride to catch up. The fastest pursuers will stay on the chase, while the slower will keep fresh. Then, once the lead horses of both groups tire out, the refreshed horses can catch up and capture/kill the lead group.

It also depends on visibility. If it gets rainy, misty, or dark, the lead group could attempt to slip away one or two at a time, leaving only the fastest to be followed by the pursuers. The pursuers could spread out to prevent this, but might then risk being outnumbered if an attenuated front meets a concentrated group of riders.

Still, overall, I believe the advantage is with the pursuers, mainly due to their greater number.